# Set attribute when selecting option in an array of string

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a disabled input and when I have to select a specific option in my select I would like to pass it at false. A get the right value after selecting my option but i think the event isn't triggered.

The function

```
  onChange() {
    this.selectedValue;
    var r = document.getElementById('myInput'); 
    if (this.selectedValue != this.listeOfString[0]) {
      r.setAttribute('disabled', 'false');
    }
  }
```

The inputs

```
  <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onChange()">
     <option *ngFor="let string of listeOfString">
           {{ string }}
     </option>
  </select>
<input type="text" id="myInput" [(ngModel)]="myString" disabled/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" [(ngModel)]="myString" [attr.disabled]="isInputDisabled"/>`
```

TS

```
isInputDisabled: boolean;
onChange() {
    if (this.selectedValue != this.listeOfString[0]) {
      this.isInputDisabled = false;
    }
  }
```

1. Remember that Angular is Data-Based framework, so **It works better with data binding**.
2. If you have to manipulate the DOM manually, always prefer to use the [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

Probably your solution is not working because:

- Either the `id` of your input is not correct on runtime.
- Either you haven't triggered a [change detection](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) after you manually manipulate the DOM.

*PS:* **the ordering** when you are writing: `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onChange()"` **DO** matters. If you put the `(ngModelChange)` before the `2-way-binding` it will get called before the `selectedValue` changed.

Comment: What is `this.isInputDisabled`?

Comment: A property on your component.

`isInputDisabled = true;`